# Edit a property value in a property file from shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed

The title says all. i need to replace a property value whom i don't know to a different value.
i'm trying this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i "s/myprop=[^ ]*/myprop=$newvalue/g" file.properties
```

i get `sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to`s'`

I think the problem is that `$newvalue` is a string that represents a directory so it messes up sed.

What can I do ?

Comment: `/` is just the usual (but not mandatory) delimiter for `sed`. What happens if you try something else, like pipe (`|`)?

Comment: @DanFego worked ! it took me long to realize that the `/` in my var string was the problem. forgot that you can switch sed delimiter. thank you

Comment: Why do you use the `g` modifier at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sed` can use characters other than `/` as the delimiter, even though `/` is the most common. When dealing with things like pathnames, it's often helpful to use something like pipe (`|`) instead.

Comment: for some seds you'll need to 'escape' the first instance of a non-standard reg-ex delimiter, like 's\|srch|repl|'. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 10):

If your property file is delimited with `=` sign like this -

```
param1=value1
param2=value2
param3=value3
```

then you can use `awk` do modifiy the **param value** by just knowing the **param name**. For example, if we want to modify the `param2` in your property file, we can do the following -

```
awk -F"=" '/^param2/{$2="new value";print;next}1' filename > newfile
```

Now, the above `one-liner` requires you to **hard code** the new value of param. This might not be the case if you are using it in a shell script and need to get the new value from a variable.

In that case, you can do the following -

```
awk -F"=" -v newval="$var" '/^param2/{$2=newval;print;next}1' filename > newfile
```

In this we create an `awk` variable `newval` and initialize it with your script variable ($var) which contains the new parameter value.

Comment: What if I want to add a new line at the end if the property does not exist?

Comment: I've tried the `awk` command stated but it strips the `=` out of the output so ends up converting `HOSTNAME=oldvalue` to `HOSTNAME newvalue` - any idea what i've got wrong?

Comment: @Oly You'll need to set the OFS variable. So `awk -F'=' -v OFS='=' ...`

Comment: Thanks @jaypalsingh I found this nice little description of the OFS field: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/

Comment: awk: newval1=http://test:8080/testservices
awk:             ^ syntax error
I am getting syntax error for : Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How can I change more than one params?

Answer (score 3):

I found a function from someone named Kongchen. He wrote a function script to change property values and it worked fine for me:

Check it out:
https://gist.github.com/kongchen/6748525